# Windows START command, binding [Applinks]

Tags: windows, command-line, registry

During testing we want to start application with the small start command that seems to work for some applications.

> START chrome //-starts Google Chrome

This also works for Firefox, Notepad and many other applications. But our problem is that is doesn't seems to work on all machines. 'START chrome' works on 80% of our cloned testmachines, but not not on the other.

How does the START-command work when you pass e.g. 'chrome'?
Where does it look up the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, the paths are located here:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths

List all of them: 
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths" /s

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely understanding your question. If you are talking about batch files

you can have a look here http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

which looks for the windows path variable %PATH% which should have a path to where the executable are located.

Hope this helps

Comment: I know the start command that is used to start batch files, but the command also seems to work with apps in windows. e.g. start chrome, even though chrome.exe isn't in your %PATH%